# Adding React.js to an existing Electron App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, electron, desktop-application

I am developing a desktop application using Electron.js. Now, I decided that to implement the required functionality, it would be good to use React.js. I searched for some tutorials on how to add React to an existing electron app, but all I got was tutorials on building React apps with Electron from "scratch". Also, all those tutorials add electron on top of an existing React app and not the other way round. I haven't found any existing stackoverflow answers addressing this problem.

I don't want to go through the mess of creating a new project and then copying the existing code to the new project. This would also mean I would loose all the older commits from my Git and I want to continue with this project on the same repo.

Could anyone help me figure this out?